# Add <br> between text in string

Tags: javascript, tags, charat

I've the following function:

```
var index = 0;
var text = 'Hello world!';
function type() {
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
  index += 1;
  var t = setTimeout('type()',200);
}
```

I want to know if is possible to make it add a br tag between the words hello and world.

I tried like that: 'hello' + br tag + 'world'; but didn't work, probably because of the charAt.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var index = 0;
var text = 'Hello world!';
var textLength = text.length;
var elScreen = document.getElementById('screen');
(function type() {
  var charToType = text.charAt(index);
  if (charToType === ' ') {
    charToType = '<br />';
  }
  elScreen.innerHTML += charToType;
  index += 1;
  if (index < textLength) {
    setTimeout(type, 200);
  }
})();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T6qT7/). The key idea is very simple: when the character to be processed next is whitespace, it's replaced with `<br />`.

Note two other changes here:

- one can use function reference (instead of string) as setTimeout first param. In fact, one should use it this way.
- unless there's a very big reason to do so, one should stop 'typing' that string when its end is reached - hence the `index < textLength` check.

Comment: if I want to have a bigger string, it adds a br tag in every space. Any way to change that? thanks

Comment: Well, you have different strategies in this case. You can either define places where `<br />` is to be inserted with some special character (guaranteed to be not in the string normally, like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yksk/)) - or place `<br />` inside the original string, and treat any `<` symbol collected with `charAt` as mark of this tag ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Avc5L/)).